# Can DELL Monitors in use on Windows XP be too old to transfer to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two 24 inch. high-resolution [Dell monitors (Model No. 2405FPW)](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=22&l=en&s=dfh&sku=320-4237&validate=false&~lt=popup) on a Windows XP desktop, and using NVIDIA Quoadro NVS290 working perfectly.

In trying to update to a Windows 10 computer, the display cannot be adjusted properly. I was told that updating the drivers is not an option, and that the monitors are too old to be used on the new computer.

Is this information correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is a freaking standard monitor. It will work with any OS.

You might not have a monitor file to calibrate or specify specific settings for that screen, but just using a generic display setting will work fine.

PS: Posted using win10 and a Dell 2407 WFP (same era, closely related model).
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have no clue of hardware issues, so can I ask you very simply  if we just need new drivers (and where to get them), or we need any specific form of software?

Comment: I did not load any drivers for the 2407WFP. (I did load other drivers, e.g. graphics card drivers, netowkr card drivers, .... but none for the old dell).